# How to implement value-like semantics for non-trivial types in rust

Tags: rust, traits, ownership

I would like to write a type that has an implementation for the `Drop` trait. but I would like to not need to call `.clone()` every time I need a copy like a type that implement `Copy`. But from what I understood, I cannot use the `Copy` trait because it can only be implemented for trivial types that can be memcpyed around and is incompatible with the `Drop` trait.

for example:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Impl {
    //... details
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct ValueLikeHandle {
    handle : Rc<Impl>
}

impl ValueLikeHandle {
    pub fn new() -> ValueLikeHandle {
        ValueLikeHandle { handle : Rc::new(Impl{}) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = ValueLikeHandle::new();
    let b = a; // I would like this to be a .clone() with out writing it.
    let c = a;
}
```

How can I implement value semantics for a non-trivial type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can't. This is a conscious design decision to prevent gotchas.

`Clone` has the potential to be expensive and therefore shouldn't happen implicitly. Also, it would be a gotcha because assignment either uses move semantics for non-copy types and copy semantics for copy types, but never clones.

In some languages you could overload the assignment operator to implement clone semantics, but Rust doesn't allow that.

Comment: Thats pretty sad....
The behavior I describe make type so much easier to work with in some contexts (sometimes at the cost of some performance).
Having the feature I describes as an opt-in for type writers makes the "gotcha" perfectly  acceptable IMHO.

Comment: @Tyker There were discussions about that (I don't have time to search now, but search on IRLO). Some people agree with you, I personally don't.